# What is the sum of natural numbers to an even power?

Tags: natural-numbers

We know $\sum_{0}^{N}m^2=\frac{N(N+1)(2N+1)}{6}$.

Is there a generic expression for $\sum_{0}^{N}m^n$ where $n$ is an even number?

Comment: Search for Bernoulli numbers.

Comment: $\sum_{m=1}^N m^n=\frac{(N+1+B)^{n+1}-B^{n+1}}{n+1}$. See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/642625/how-is-the-bernoulli-numbers-for-example-as-against-b-2/642689#642689 to find the value of $B^n\Doteq B_n$ for any arbitrary $n$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I compute the sum of this formula $ \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{100} i^8- 2 i^2 $](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/539474/how-can-i-compute-the-sum-of-this-formula-displaystyle-sum-i-1100-i8-2)

Answer (score 1):

There is actually an expression for that sum when $n$ is any natural number in terms of the Bernoulli numbers. In particular it will hold when $n$ is an even natural number. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula

Comment: You're very welcome.